# Relation between $a_{-p}$ and $a^{\dagger}$? for real scalar field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation

Fast question. Consider the real Klein-Gordon field. Is there a way to relate $a_{-p}$ with $a_p^{\dagger}$?

Answer (score 1):

From this [Lubos Motl's answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/135952/58382):

> Obviously, it can't be true that a creation operator is equal to an annihilation operator. They are qualitatively different (each annihilation operator annihilates the vacuum, while no creation operator does so) so they cannot be equal.

If this does not answer your question, please specify what you mean with "relation".

Comment: with relation I mean an equation which would allow me to write one in function of the other

Comment: @silvrfück then my answer provides you with the solution: no

Comment: what is the equation relating them? i dont see it

Comment: @silvrfück there isn't, they are different objects